# invoke the IntentService from onDestroy

Tags: android

I want to empty the table on the server side for a mac address when the user closes the application.  Therefor, I am starting the IntentService class from the `onDestroy()` method in the MainActivity but the Service is *not being* started. I have already registered it in the Manifest. When I put the code in onDestroy in `onStop()` the Service starts.

I cant do this job in `onPause()` or `onStop` since the app must be able to record data `(latitude, longitude, Speed, mac and time)` in the Background.

If it is not possible in this way How can I manage it?

**onDestroy in the MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

     JsonObject  jsonObject = new  JsonObject();
     jsonObject.addProperty("mac", macAddress);

    System.out.println("JsonObject" + jsonObject);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            ClearTable.class);
    intent2.putExtra("json_mac", json);
    startService(intent2);
```

}

**IntentService class:**

```
public class ClearTable extends IntentService{

    public ClearTable() {
        super("IntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_mac");
            System.out.println("xyz The output of : doInBackground "
                    + jSONString);
            URL myUrl = new URL(
                    "https://serverside-apple.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.connect();             
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
            wr.close();             
            System.out.println("xyz The output of getResponsecode: "
             + conn.getResponseCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

**Manifest:**

```
 <service android:name=".ClearTable" />
```

Comment: `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, hence putting important piece of code in it is dangerous.

Comment: So where else can I put it in my case?

Comment: can you please accept my answer ?

Comment: Just an idea: you could also schedule a table-cleanup to occur in a timely manner on your server. Relying on the client to inform the server that it is no longer present seems like a bad design as it creates a memory leak: any malicious third-party may spawn multiple clients to fill up your server's client map. If the third-party then abruptly terminates the client applications, you have a lot of dead objects residing in your map which will never be removed as you're planning to only remove them when informed of their lack of relevance through a client call.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying your luck with `onDestroy()` , which is very unreliable as its not guaranteed to be called you should decide something else:

As you stated in your question:

> I want to empty the table on the server side for a mac address when the user closes the application.

So why don't you override the `onBackPressed()` method of the base Activity(Launching Activity) ? and handle your logic in their.

**EDIT**

After OP's comment about doing something, when user closes the app in background:
No!! There is no reliable way to check/detect when your app gets killed in the background either user forcefully closes or System decides to kill it, in case it needs to recover memory.

Comment: Because I want to delete the records on the server side in this case when the user closes the app in the Background.

Comment: when user closes the app in the background.. well there is no way to handle this situation .. trust me on this one.. wasted way too much time for something like this myself

Comment: Also the Problem with `onBackPressed()` that the user can close the app without pressing the back button or the user will never press the back button in one activity because the previous activity is the splash activity alsp it makes no sense to press it in this case.

Comment: your splash activity should be showed only once, not again when back is pressed.. and like i stated, there is no reliable way in your scenario.. most people do their cleaning in `onPause()` method, but again if the device is in lock or screen turn black and application is still running, then `onPause()` will be called..